# C++ executable with C shared library segfault: Function argument cannot access memory at address 0xfff

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, arm64

I have this segfault in some application and as far as I saw there are some things that get f'ed up.

First of all, this is on aarch64 (arm64).

Basically, I have a C++(11) application which uses libmongoose which is a C shared library.

```
void some_class::some_function_in_CPP_application()
{
    // local mg_connect_opts object
    struct mg_connect_opts opts;

    // setting some stuff in the opts
    opts.error_string = &err_str;
    opts.user_data = this;

    // sending "opts" by value
    struct mg_connection *nc = mg_connect_ws_opt(mgr, ev_handler, opts, uri, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

The signature of "mg_connect_ws_opt" is as follows (in the C shared library):

```
struct mg_connection *mg_connect_ws_opt(
    struct mg_mgr *mgr, MG_CB(mg_event_handler_t ev_handler, void *user_data),
    struct mg_connect_opts opts, const char *url, const char *protocol,
    const char *extra_headers);
```

So, the "opts" param is received by copy and everything should be fine.

However, when I check the callstack in the core dump I get something like this:
1.In the C++ code, before the mg_connect_http_opt function is called(I changed the actual values but these are proper):

```
(gdb) print opts
$5 = {
  user_data = 0x7fe8e70f40, 
  flags = 0, 
  error_string = 0x5569ba17b8 <err_str>, 
  iface = 0x0, 
  nameserver = 0x0, 
  ssl_cert = 0x0, 
  ssl_key = 0x0, 
  ssl_ca_cert = 0x0, 
  ssl_cipher_suites = 0x556965e850 "PSKADJSAFSAK", 
  ssl_server_name = 0x0, 
  ssl_psk_identity = 0x55a07451a0 "21321521321321312312321", 
  ssl_psk_key = 0x55a0742e20 "43124321rsafsa32131zcxbsa"
}
```

This is perfectly fine, everything is good. But, when I go to the next frame in the callstack, directly in the mg_connect_ws_opt function in the C lib I get this:

```
(gdb) frame 4
#4  0x0000007fb59fdfd4 in mg_connect_ws_opt (mgr=<optimized out>, 
    ev_handler=<optimized out>, 
    opts=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff>, url=<optimized out>, protocol=0x0, extra_headers=0x0)
(gdb) print opts
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I don't get why the parameter is bad since it is taken by copy.

Is it possible that the problem is maybe some calling convention difference between C++ and C?
If that is the case, would it help marking the "some_function_in_CPP_application" as extern "C"?

Also, I am only able to do postmortem debugging using the core dump. I have very limited debugging possibilities...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can, rebuild the application and the library with optimizations disabled and see whether the debugger will provide more details. Also if you can, compile with address sanitizer enabled or run under valgrind to see whether you are overwriting the stack somewhere. No, you should not (and you can't) mark the function `extern "C"`. With the information given there isn't really more to say than give generic debugging advice I fear.

Comment: However, what seems dubious is `struct mg_connect_opts opts;`. First of all in C++, the `struct` keyword is redundant here and at best hides potential typos. Remove it. Second, the line does not zero-initialize the structure. Are you setting _all_ fields afterwards? You have to or otherwise you need to zero-initialize the variable e.g. by writing `mg_connect_opts opts{};`.

Comment: You are right. Related to the initialization, I agree but in this case, I don't think it's the problem, since I can see the values in the debugger before calling "mg_connect_ws_opt". But yes, I will do that.

Comment: And also, @user17732522 very good directions provided here. Will see what I can do.

Comment: When you have memory corruption you cannot expect meaningful results of anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik noted. I'm trying to compile with address sanitizer and maybe I can run some tests or something. Hopefully, it will give me something useful.

Comment: If you show the whole stack (output of "bt"...) that will likely make it easier to help you.